# Pass file path as parameter in Flask app.route()

Tags: python-3.x, flask, url-parameters, urlparse

Here is my code. I'm trying to take the file path in as a parameter but the "/" in the path between directories is making the method treat the directories as separate parameters.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<a>/<b>/<c>/<d>/<e>/<f>')
def url(a, e, b, c, d, f):
    if f == '':
        f = 'index.html'
    print(f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=80)
```

Basically the variable f is supposed to take the file path (a,b,c,d,e are just other parameters) and the method is treating f as multiple parameters when there's a / inputted. 
Are there any fixes without changing the splitting variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/<a>/<b>/<c>/<d>/<e>/<path:f>')
```

See: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/76/

Comment: It seems like it should've worked, but didn't. Same error as before. The method is even being called.